# VIM: function that checks if external program is running

Tags: process, vim, function

Using a vim function, I would like to check if a program is running using pgrep, and if it is not running then do something. In particular, I want to achieve something like this:

```
function! checkifrunning(mystring)
    if 'pgrep "mystring"' shows that something is NOT running
        --do something--
    endif
endfunction
```

My guess is that I need to use the 'system()' function, but I'm not sure how. Can somebody help?

EDIT: I would like a solution that uses pgrep in particular, and not some other way

Comment: If you're interested in Vim, do check out sister site [vi.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function! checkifrunning(mystring)
    if !system('pgrep "' . a:mystring . '"')
        " --do something--
    endif
endfunction
```

Technically [`!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-%21) operates on [Numbers](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#Number), and converts a String to a Number first if given a String. However, if there's no process running, the output of `pgrep` will be empty, which when converted to a Number is 0. If there are process running, conversion to a Number would give non-zero.

Instead of `'pgrep "' . a:mystring . '"'`, you could also do `'pgrep ' . shellescape(a:mystring)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
:call system("pgrep process name ")
```

To print the output ,

```
:echo system("pgrep process name ")
```

You can store the output in a variable like

```
:let a=system("pgrep process name ")
```

And, use that variable in any loop, print, or use string functions as well.